# C# List Object display and filter input dotnet mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to do this for a while and need some help badly.
I installed the new visual studio on my mac as well as dotnet mvc. I have created a simple app and can't figure this out at all. I'm new to dot net MVC so that is part of the issue. I am not up on the terminology yet but have been reading through docs to try and figure this out but to no avail.

Here is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using softwareversion.Models;

namespace softwareversion.Controllers
{
    public class SoftwareController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Data()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my Models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace softwareversion.Models
{
    public class Software
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my Views:

```
@model IEnumerable<softwareversion.Models.Software>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Search Versions";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="get" action="" class="">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<table class="table">

    <tr>
        <td>
            {{List.Name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{List.Version}}
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

Here is the rest of the code i was sent:

```
 public class Fake {
   public string Name {    get;  set;  }
   public string Version { get;  set;  }
 }

 public static class FakeManager {
  public static IEnumerable < Fake > GetAllFake() {
   return new List < Fake > {
    new Fake {
     Name = “Hello World”,
      Version = "13.2.1."
    },
    new Fake {
     Name = "Hello World",
      Version = "1.7.1"
    },
    new Fake {
     Name = "Hello World",
      Version = "8.1.13"
    },
    new Fake {
     Name = "Hello World",
      Version = "0.0.5"
    },
    new Fake {
     Name = "Hello World",
      Version = "2.6"
    },
    new Fake {
     Name = "Hello World",
      Version = "2017.0.1"
    },
    new Fake {
     Name = "Hello World",
      Version = "2019.1"
    },
    new Fake {
     Name = "Hello World",
      Version = "1.35"
    },
    new Fake {
     Name = "Hello World",
      Version = "0.7"
    }
   };
  }
 }
```

Rest of the instructions I was sent:
They have asked us to create a simple website where users can type in a version number and receive a list of software products that are greater than the version they entered.

The software versions are stored as a string in the format [major version].[minor version].[patch]. You may see versions like “2”, “1.5”, or “2.12.4” (these are all valid inputs from the user as well). The period is only used as a separator and does not represent a decimal point – 1.5 does not mean one and a half.

```
"2" == "2.0" == "2.0.0"
"2" < "2.0.1"
"2" < "2.1"
"2.0.1" < "2.1.0"
```

Lucky for you, they stored the software list as a C# object (provided above) that you can simply drop into your code – no need to call a database or REST service.

UPDATE:
I edited my controller and now I am getting this error

```
My controller is now giving an error when I search:
```

[image: Error]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebApplication2.Models;


namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class SoftwareController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var softwares = SoftwareManager.GetAllSoftware();
            return View(softwares);
        }

        public IActionResult GetFilteredVersion(string filter = "")
        {
            var softwares = SoftwareManager.GetAllSoftware();
            char[] charsToTrim = { '.', ' ', '\'' };

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
                return View(softwares);

            var Result = softwares.Select(o => new { Version = Version.Parse(o.Version), original = o });

            if (filter == "")
                filter = "0.0.0";
            else
                filter = filter.Trim(charsToTrim).Replace(".", "0");

            var compareVersions = Version.Parse(filter);
            var greaterVersions = Result.Where(o => o.Version >= compareVersions);


            var filtered = Result.Where(a => a.Version > compareVersions).Select(o => o.original);
            return View(filtered);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but you might want to look at the [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netcore-3.0) class. It provides the ability to [parse a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.-ctor?view=netcore-3.0#System_Version__ctor_System_String_) version and do [comparisons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netcore-3.0#comparing-version-objects).

Comment: My question is how do i get this on the view of Software. I am not getting this part. I am a super noob at dotnet and MVC

Comment: You need to use a mask

Comment: Ahh what? ANy code help examples links something soi can read up on the solution and get this complete?

Comment: @Chris Can you message me on here? I think I know how to ask a better question to get an answer to this question. Thanks!)

Comment: @user2025730 as per my understanding you want to filter records on version basis inside textbox and for that you need to use ajax with partial view https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: You are getting this error because you called Version.Parse with a string that does not contain any separators.  You removed them with `.Replace(".", "0")`.  Remove that part, and it should work better.

Comment: Also, since your GetFilteredVersion returns all the software when you don't pass in any value, you can merge this with the Index method.

Comment: @RobertMcKee That makes sense. I got that done. Still can not figure out this Parse portion of the code. Do you have a second to chat?

Comment: Here is my fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Qu2TB?fbclid=IwAR1KGruswUKEl9NmpM-g6MsDQMUbk02TzOyZomSmBV-yuSPyn5UJNY2IJT4

Comment: This one works but does not filter like i need it to - https://dotnetfiddle.net/0TSDkp?fbclid=IwAR31wLYmGMJVMbdKGqRIp64jP01vSMyhr-9Sja0Jpa5GgiSJV_3MKpKmcys

Comment: Closer:https://dotnetfiddle.net/CsBacw

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet due to low rep so posting as an answer instead. Working from Robert Mckee's Controller code for parsing the search string; I think all that was missing was returning the results back to the View as a ToList:

```
public IActionResult Index(string versionSearch)
    {
        if (versionSearch != null)
        {
            var model = FakeManager.GetAllFake();
            char[] trim = { '.', ' ', '\'' };
            versionSearch = versionSearch.Trim(trim);

            var compare = new Version(versionSearch);
            var result = model.Where(v => Version.Parse(v.Version.Trim(trim)) >= compare);

            return View(result.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            var model = FakeManager.GetAllFake();
            return View(model.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Here's the View code I used, but it's very similar again:

```
@model IEnumerable<[YourProjectNameHere].Models.Fake>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Search Versions";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="get" action="" class="">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Search by Version:
        @Html.TextBox("VersionSearch")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}

    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                @item.Name
                <br />
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                @item.Version
                <br />
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When filtering, it now excludes version numbers lower than the search string while including the version numbers that are higher (also tested against the Minor and Patch numbers):
[image]